# Can not execute a function in a component context

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to execute `bubbleData` function which is in the app controller

The following ways didn't work.

```
this.get("data").call();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
this.get("data")();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
this.get("data")()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

### Console output : by typing this.get('data') in the Component draw function

```
function (){
    var self = this;    
    debugger;
    return {
      name: 'tools',
      children: this.get("data").map(function(t){
        return{
          name: t.name,
          size: 300
        }
      })
    };

  }
```

### View

```
{{bubble-chart width=560 height=350 data=bubbleData}}
```

### Controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  bubbleData: function(){
    var self = this;    
    debugger;
    return {
      name: 'tools',
      children: this.get("data").map(function(t){
        return{
          name: t.name,
          size: 300
        }
      })
    };
  },....
```

### Component

```
App.BubbleChartComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  draw: function(){
    debugger;
  }.observes('data').on('didInsertElement')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The component can send an action by using the `sendAction` function (http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/).

So the proper way would be in **hbs**

```
data="bubbleData"
```

and in **js** of component

```
this.sendAction("data");
```

**example**

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/luwixanemunu/1/edit

If however it is required to pass the function itself, then care must be taken for the context that calls the function. This is the reason that `this.get("data")();` does not work. In the example `test2` demonstrates the proper way of calling it,

```
var theController = this.get("parentView.controller");
      this.get("data2").apply(theController);
```

The example's code

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>


    {{bubble-chart width=560 height=350 data="bubbleData2" data2=bubbleData test=testProp}}   


  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/bubble-chart">
  the bubble component <br/>
  {{test}}
  <br/>
  <button {{action "test1"}}>test1</button>
  <button {{action "test2"}}>test2</button>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  testProp:"test",
  bubbleData: function(){
    var self = this;    
    debugger;
    return {
      name: 'tools',
      children: this.get("data").map(function(t){
        return{
          name: t.name,
          size: 300
        };
      })
    };
  },
  actions:{
    bubbleData2:function(){alert("bubbleData in actions");}
  }
});



App.BubbleChartComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  draw: function(){
//     debugger;
  }.observes('data').on('didInsertElement'),
  actions:{
    test1:function(){
      this.sendAction("data");
    },
    test2:function(){
      var theController = this.get("parentView.controller");
      this.get("data2").apply(theController);
    }
  }

});
```